# Problem with YUM

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I've recently registered a VPS and am trying to update the version of PHP installed on it. I'm used to Ubuntu rather than Redhat so I need a bit of advice on how to solve this problem.

Yum seems to be having a bit of a nightmare, I've tried installing it but at various points get to error messages or dead links and haven't found anything near a recent tutorial online.

When I run `rpm -q yum` I get `yum-3.2.22-26.el5.centos` so I think to an extent my installation was succesful however when I run `yum` then I get the following response:

```
`Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Mar  6 2011, 09:56:34) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq`
```

Nothing in the FAQ seems to be working. Any ideas as to whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're issue is you upgraded the system python. Yum has a lot of python modules that you broke by upgrading python.

It is saying you have version 2.7 installed but no redhat 5 has 2.4.

You need to install a valid rpm version for python2.7 which doesn't kill the 2.4 install

Answer (score 2):

You've replaced the system Python, which yum is installed against. Get the `python` package via HTTP and use rpm to install it.

Comment: which python package should I be looking to get?

Comment: THE `python` package. From CentOS.